# How to get an instance of org.springframework.validation.Errors for unit testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am writing unit test for a controller method that has the following signature

```
String handlerApplicationRequest(@ModelAttribute("resource") Resource resource, Errors errors, HttpServletRequest request)
```

to call this method i my unit test, i need to pass all three arguments, 
I already have an instance of Resource, for testing and i created MockHttpServletRequest instance for the request. But i don't know how to get an instance of org.springframework.validation.Errors. The spring documentation, I don't see any public constructor or any static factory method to instantiate this class.
The code i am writing unit test for is not my code but its documentation says, that Errors, holds any errors in processing the request. My question is how can i get an instance of Errors to write my unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any public constructors because [org.springframework.validation.Errors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) is an interface. See the "All known implementing classes" section of the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) to find an implementation that you can construct and pass into your test.

The option that is most appropriate for unit tests is to create a mock implementation of the interface using a mocking framework (e.g. [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) or [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)). You then define expectations against the mock to test that your class under test is behaving correctly. It's usually a bad idea to test multiple classes simulatenously, which if you use a real implementation of `Errors`, your unit test will be coupled to the implementation of that interface.

Comment: i did not even look at the documentation carefully to see that it was actually an interface not a class. thanks